# Making a new column and setting default values equal to the COUNT of a certain condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables. (table1, table2)
Now, I would like to do something along the lines of:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 
ADD counter INT DEFAULT (Select COUNT(table2.car_type)
                         FROM table2
                         WHERE (table1.car_type = table2.car_type));
```

That's the closest syntax I can come up with, but just by looking at it I know it's wrong. Please tell me how to do it in ONE SQL statement (if possible).

The goal table (with counter implemented) is something like this: (separated columns by -)

table1:
`pid-car_type-counter`:

```
1-Honda-2
2-Toyota-3
3-Suzuki-1
4-Ferrari-0
5-Porsche-1
```

table2:
`pid-car_type`:

```
1-Honda
2-Toyota
3-Porsche
4-Honda
5-Suzuki
6-Toyota
7-Toyota
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this, at least through 11g.  FTFM:

> Restriction on Default Column Values: A DEFAULT expression cannot
>   contain references to PL/SQL functions or to other columns, the
>   pseudocolumns CURRVAL, NEXTVAL, LEVEL, PRIOR, and ROWNUM, or date
>   constants that are not fully specified.

I'm fairly certain you can't use a SELECT statement in a DEFAULT clause, either.  There might be a way with virtual columns.  Another alternative is to create a view.